# CF - MenuItem selection in MainMenu

Tags: compact-framework, menuitem, selecteditem

Again i wonder how can i highlight selected item in my MainMenu form.
Every time i select an item only the first item is highlighted (always the same).
But when a MenuItem is clicked its highlighted untill the Menu reloads.

I found "checked" property on MenuItem that would generaly work, but the first item remains highlighted. There is no other properties on menuItem such as background color or selected...

Can some one please direct me to the right solution?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to either create your own or you can use OpenNETCFs...I highly suggest the latter.

Take a look at this:

<strike>http://www.opennetcf.com/Default.aspx?tabid=120</strike>
http://web.archive.org/web/20111016215645/http://www.opennetcf.com/Default.aspx?tabid=120

Comment: ughh... looks painfull (just like CF really is). But thanx for the anwser .... looks like im gonna have to look into this OpenNETCF sonner then i thought. I was avoiding it with using my own controls made with panels etc (for instance instead of using Listbox from OpenNETCF that dont have horisontal scrool i creadted seperated view for each row while the main view is a panel that supports horisontal scrolls...) ... anyway thanx for the anwser !